# grpc-web - how to get response headers

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, grpc, response-headers, grpc-web

I'm using `grpc-web` in react app and calling the endpoint which results in returning error:

> Error: Response closed without grpc-status (Headers only)

```
getCurrent(callback: (user: User | null, err: ServiceError | null) => void) {
  const request = new Empty();
  const client = new UserServiceClient(Config.beUrl);

  client.getMyself(request, getGRPCMetadata(), (err, res) => {
    const user = res ? mapResponse(userMapping)(res) : null;

    callback(user, err);
  });
}
```

When I call this request, in response headers I see (in chrome's devtools):

```
Grpc-Message: Insufficient privileges, roles=[IAM/ADMIN], permission=IAM/IMPERSONATE
```

But I am not able to get the header from response. `console.log(err.metadata)` only returns:

```
{
    "headersMap": {
        "content-length": [
            "0"
        ],
        "content-type": [
            "application/grpc-web+proto"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the response headers?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be related to the proxy configuration, especially if you're using Envoy between your gRPC server and the `grpc-web` client.

In the `Envoy` configuration, there's a filter named `HttpConnectionManager` which can have `cors` rules attached to it. Within these rules, there's an `expose_headers` field. If certain headers aren't listed there, they won't be exposed to the client, which might be the reason you can't access them.

For instance, if your configuration looks like this:

```yaml
expose_headers: x, y, z
```

...you'd want to ensure that the headers you're trying to access (e.g., grpc-message, roles and permission) are also listed.

```yaml
expose_headers: x, y, z, grpc-message, roles, permission
```

If you are indeed using Envoy as your proxy, I'd recommend checking and possibly updating this configuration.